# Mysql equivalent rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am new to rails. What is the equivalent rails query for the following sql query?

```
mysql> select a.code, b.name, b.price, b.page from article a inner join books b on a.id =b.article_id;
```

I am trying

```
Article.joins(:books).select("books.name, books.price, books.page, articles.code")
```

The active record relation returns only table one data

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Article id: 1, code: "x", created_at: "2014-11-12 13:28:08", updated_at: "2014-11-14 04:16:06">, #<Article id: 2, code: "y", created_at: "2014-11-12 13:28:08", updated_at: "2014-11-14 04:00:16">]>
```

What is the solution to join both table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally don't really query like that directly with Rails. Instead, you'd set up your models and use other associated models to achieve this. If speed is an issue, you can use eager loading. If you absolutely need exactly this join, it's:

```ruby
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  scope :with_books, lambda { 
    joins(:books)
      .select('articles.code, books.name, books.price, books.page') 
  }
end 

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

But this is not so useful. It generates the join you want, but retrieving the book details like that won't be fun. You could do something like:

```ruby
a = Article.with_books.where("books.name = 'Woken Furies'").first
a.code
```

And that should give you the article code. Depending on what you need, a better way could be to **remove** the scope from the `Article` class and instead query like:

```ruby
b = Book.where(name: 'Woken Furies')
      .joins(:article)
      .where("articles.code = 'something'")

b = Book.where("name = 'Woken Furies' AND articles.code = 'something'")
      .joins(:article)
```

Both of these queries should be equivalent. You can get from one associated record to the other with:

```ruby
book = b.first
article_code = book.article.code
```

I'm not sure what you need to accomplish with the join, but I think you might get more beautiful code by using plain ActiveRecord. If you need the speed gain, avoid n+1 problems, etc., it might make sense to write those joins out by hand.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

There's more about joining in the Rails guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

**Update:** You can use `pluck` if you need to retrieve e.g. just the code and the name:

```ruby
Article.with_books
  .where("books.name = 'Woken Furies'")
  .pluck('articles.code, books.name')
```